# 3D curve interpolation using gnuplot

Tags: 3d, gnuplot, interpolation

I have a data file containing some points belonging to a spiral-like 3d curve. My goal is to create a smooth trajectory using Gnuplot's `splot` . I have tried to find an equivalent command to two dimensional `plot` ... `smooth csplines`, but without succeeding in it.

I believe that if Gnuplot is able to interpolate whole surfaces, there has to be a tool to interpolate curves. Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide a min working example as per the community guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The development branch of gnuplot (version 5.5) supports spline-smoothed curves in 3D.  Earlier versions do not. From the v5.5 documentation:

```
 Smoothing in 3D plots (splot) is currently limited to generating a natural
 cubic spline to pass through a set of 3D points.  In the general case
 the splines are generated along a trajectory (`smooth path`).  For a 2D
 projection of 3D data `smooth csplines` acts as it does in 2D.
 Either keyword is accepted in an `splot` command.

      splot $DATA using 1:2:3 smooth path with lines
```

Comment: Than you very much!